# iOS: scan BLE devices when screen OFF always receive nil on CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Follow Core Bluetooth Programming Guide on Apple Developer site, I'm developing an application run on iOS 8 using BLE to connect with a specified device (by CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey in advertising data).
The callback centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI: works right and it can get CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey in advertisementData when app in background state, screen ON. When screen OFF, data get from CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey in advertisementData: always takes nil.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: I believe this is due to power saving when the screen is off.  However, you shouldn't rely on the name to identify the device, you should use service and UUID information.

Comment: I also think so. Service UUID is not enough, because many devices can have the same Service UUID. Device UUID is not permanent and can be changed due to some reasons.

Comment: I know that the UUID of a non-bonded iOS peripheral (an iOS device using CBPeripheralManager) can change but I haven't had a problem with standard BLE peripherals changing their UUID.  This is what I store in order to connect to a specific peripheral.